# Numerical derivative of compoiste function

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, function-and-relation-composition, finite-differences

sorry for the very basic question. I am writing a Fortran program in which I have a quite complicated function in a non-linear system of equations and I need to differentiate it numerically in order to get a member of the Jacobian for solving the system with the Newton-Raphson method. The question is... being a composite function like

$$g(f(x))$$

is the numerical derivative (central difference formula) simply:

$$ \dfrac{\partial g(f(x))}{\partial x} = \dfrac{g(f(x+h)) - g(f(x-h))}{2h}$$

?

Do I need to change this formula according to the chain rule?

Regards.

Comment: That's the formula, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You have
$$F(x)=g(f(x))$$
and want to find
$$\frac{\mathrm dF(x)}{\mathrm dx}.$$

By definition,
$$\frac{\mathrm dF(x)}{\mathrm dx}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}$$
or, almost equivalently,
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x-h)}{2h}.$$

Now, given the definition of $F$ as $F(x)=g(f(x))$, evaluate:
$$\frac{F(x+h)-F(x-h)}{2h}=\frac{g(f(x+h))-g(f(x-h))}{2h}.$$

Taking the limit will give the derivative or substituting a small $h$ will give a numerical approximation to it, no matter if $F$ is constructed via composition of two functions or not.

Comment: Just a clarification to the OP: the **no** here is an answer to the question "Do I need to change this formula?", while my **yes** in the comments is an answer to the question "Is this formula correct".